# JSF MySQL Project in inputText first thing I display value, but when submit it after modifications (through binding) it passed original values

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

JSF MySQL Project in inputText first thing I display value from DB, but when submit it after modifications (through binding) it passed original values that I received from MySQL Database.

Here is form:

```
<h:form>
            User name:
            <h:inputText 
                value="#{customer.customer.name}"
                binding="#{username}">    
            </h:inputText>
            <br/>

            Password:
            <h:inputText 
                value="#{customer.customer.password}"
                binding="#{pass}">    
            </h:inputText>
            <br/>

        <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Modify" action="#{customer.modifyUser(customer.customer.id, username.value, pass.value)}"/>
    </h:form>
```

Java code for taking data from DB by id, that i pass from previous page (it displays the data correctly):

```
public Customer getCustomer() {
    Customer cxx = new Customer();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" + id;
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        cxx.setId(id);
        cxx.setName(rs.getString("login"));
        cxx.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error_query_getCust: " + ex);
    }
    return cxx;

}
```

Java code to modify data in DB by id:

```
public void modifyUser(int id, String username, String pass) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        String query = "UPDATE users SET login='"+ username +"', password = '"+ pass +"' WHERE id=" + id;
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.println("User: , "+ username +", modified successfully!");
            setResultHelper("Thank you! User: , "+ username +", modified successfully!");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error_create: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's the original values, may be you use original values in the query? Are you still using JSF? What if your fields aren't properly bound? These and later clarifications on this question required, without it it's impossible to help.

Comment: I can see in Debug mode that  "submit"commandButton send original data  as attributes to method modifyUser(). By original data I mean data which I took from Database. But I need to send data that I modify.

Comment: Yes whole project is JSF. That's on of my goal to use JSF only.

Comment: I think fields are properly bound, because I use same binding on create new record in DB, and it works properly. The only difference, I do not mention value="" in createrecoerd.xhtml page. May be that is why it send value from DB, but not what i modify!!??

Answer (score -1):

I think my Java code is fine, coz the problem comes from xHTML page, it does not send modified value, but sends original value that I take from DB!

I just need to find another way to dispaly value from DB in h:inputText, then modify them in same h:inputText and send modified data to method modifyUser(int id, String username, String pass).

Comment: Your backing bean code is **absolutely not** fine. Your XHTML also not, by the way. I strongly recommend to get yourself a sane JSF book. The code which you've so far can impossibly originate from a self-respected JSF book.

Comment: Can you please tell me how XHTML should look like to send proper data?